# For Janrain Sign In with Facebook, how to configure website and app domains on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, janrain

The instructions from Janrain for social login provider setup conflict with the hint within the error message from the Facebook https response. Details follow.

Error screen when testing Facebook from Janrain; note that same error happens in any browser such as Firefox, Chrome if you test the sign-in widget.
[image]

Error Text from Facebook:
**App domains must match** the domain of the Facebook Web Games URL (https), Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, **Site URL** or Secure Page Tab URL. 
Please correct these domains: (snip).

Based on the hints from the Janrain Facebook Provider Setup wizard, I have set the website to the URL on rpxnow (i.e. definitely not my web site).

[image]

What URL(s) should then be entered into Basic and/or Advanced Settings such that Facebook can process the login?  I have tried using the rpxnow URLs and my own web site URLs.  Either of 2 things happens regardless of whether I include https:// or start from the subdomain of any combination of names.  Either Facebook will not save the details on Basic App Domain and gives the above error, or Facebook will save the details but then gives the error in the first screenshot above.

I do not see how this can ever work because Facebook wants a match on the domain and rpxnow will never be the domain that I use to invoke the sign-in.

For completeness, I will show my Facebook settings, so it will be obvious that they do not match the current Janrain Setup Guide for Facebook.

### Basic Settings

Is the Namespace relevant? Better to leave blank? Does it need to match something within Janrain?

[image]

### Advanced Settings

[image]

[image]

[image]

I could believe that something has to be done to allow cross-domain access.  Does anyone have this working with a new Janrain account (3 weeks old) and a new Facebook developer account (old Facebook account, new developer app)?

Comment: Try leaving the "App Domains" empty or just "YOUR_APP_NAME.rpxnow.com" . Don't include the "http://" at the front.  Also you may need to turn on the "Allow Cross Domain Share Redirects" - that is new feature of the Facebook api 2.11.

Comment: Tried again with App Domains empty.  Tried with my APP_NAME.rpxnow.com as the App Domain.  Omitted https:// at the beginning each time.  Turned on the "Allow Cross Domain Share Redirects" in all tests.  Nothing worked.  Always this error: "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."  How long do you think it is necessary to wait, after changing Facebook settings, before re-testing?  I tried with minutes and a couple of hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replying as an answer so I can attach a picture.

I have a feeling this might be something to do with Facebook's impending changes to their app security (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/12/18/strict-uri-matching/ ).  It appears that you need to add the Valid OAuth redirect URI for any new API v2.11 apps now (not after March).  We were already planning to address this before March but we will have to update sooner.

For your Facebook app you will have to set up the "Valid oAuth redirect URIs" similar to the following screen shot, just replace "pbjanraintest" with whatever your Engage app name is: [image]

Sorry for all the trouble you have had.  It's hard to keep up with these providers when the messaging doesn't align with what their apps and api's are actually doing.

Comment: I had not even seen the additional configuration pages under Facebook Login > Settings. Under "Client OAuth Settings", both Client OAuth Login and Web OAuth Login defaulted to YES for my new facebook app, so obviously facebook needed the whitelist.  What a relief to have this working.  Muchos gracias.

Comment: Copy/paste this into the valid URIs: https://YOURAPP.rpxnow.com/facebook/callback

Answer (score 0):

I just received the same error this week. Leave off the https:// in the OAuth redirect URIs box.